# inviting friends to like business page

Tags: facebook

I am an admin on a shared business page. My partner can invite friends when we pull down build audience. Mine does not show this option it only says invite email contacts. why is this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are viewing the page AS THE PAGE then you won't be able to invite friends on your personal Facebook Profile.

So make sure you are using Facebook as your Profile. To do that click on the cog icon on top right corner and select your profile under `Use Facebook as:` and then try inviting friends.